# Parse Nested Block Structure using ANTLR

Tags: antlr

I have this program

```
{
    run_and_branch(Test1)
    then
    {
    }
    else
    {
    }
    {
      run_and_branch(Test2)
      then
      {
      }
      else
      {
        run(Test3);
        run(Test4);
        run(Test5);
      }
    }
    run_and_branch(Test6)
    then
    {
    }
    else
    {
    }

    run(Test7);
    {
      run(Test8);
      run(Test9);
      run(Test_10);
    }

 }
```

Below is my ANLTR Grammar File

```
prog    
:   block EOF;

block   
:   START_BLOCK END_BLOCK -> BLOCK|
        START_BLOCK block* END_BLOCK -> block*|
        test=run_statement b=block* -> ^($test $b*)|
        test2=run_branch_statement THEN pass=block ELSE fail=block -> ^($test2 ^(PASS $pass) ^(FAIL $fail))
;

run_branch_statement

    :   RUN_AND_BRANCH OPEN_BRACKET ID CLOSE_BRACKET -> ID;
run_statement 

    :   RUN OPEN_BRACKET ID CLOSE_BRACKET SEMICOLON -> ID;

THEN    :    'then';

ELSE    :    'else';

RUN_AND_BRANCH     :     'run_and_branch';

RUN     :    'run';

START_BLOCK  
    :    '{' ;
END_BLOCK  
    :    '}' ;  

OPEN_BRACKET 
    :    '(';
CLOSE_BRACKET
    :   ')';    
SEMICOLON 
    :   ';'
    ;

ID  :   ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_'|'0'..'9') (':'|'%'|'='|'\''|'a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_'|'-'|'.'|'+'|'*'|'/'|'\\')*
    ;


WS  :   ( ' '
        | '\t'
        | '\r'
        | '\n'
        ) {$channel=HIDDEN;}
    ;
```

Using ANTLWorks I get the following AST:

[image: AST from ANTLRWorks]

As you can see in the AST there is no link between the Test1 and Test2 as depedency. I want to have the AST show this information so that I can traverse the AST and get the Test depedency Structure

I am expecting the AST look something like this [image: Expected AST]

Comment: "Test2" is not inside the `then` or `else` block of "Test1" so I'm not sure what you mean by "no link between the Test1 and Test2". Could you post an image of the AST you want to get instead?

Comment: I still don't understand. In your second image, the flow seems okay to me: "Test1" and then "Test2" followed by "Test6" (which is already so in image 1). Do you mean you're missing a link between "Test5" and "Test6". Realize that what you now posted is no AST, but a graph. Also, "Test7" is gone. all of a sudden...

Comment: I forgot about Test7 when I drew the second picture manually, it should be there. As you can see in second picture Test2 is child of Test1 whereas in first picture they are siblings. I want something like second picture so that I can do a DFS and determine the Test that is done in sequence. Test1 and then Test2 then Test3 etc. It is very hard to do this in the original AST that I have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ANTLR doesn't work this way. ANTLR produces a tree, not a graph, so there is no way to represent the desired output at the grammar level. In addition, if you tried to write tail-recursive rules to link control flow this way you would quickly run into stack overflow exceptions since ANTLR produces recursive-descent parsers.

You need to take the AST produced by ANTLR and perform separate control flow analysis on it to get a control flow graph.

Comment: Yep, I finally seem to have realized my mistake. I was trying to do something that cannot be done using AST :). Do you have any idea or link that I can use for transforming the AST into the CFG that I need.